# How to copy files from one server to other server with powershell when the shared path contains '$' symbol

Tags: powershell, remote-server, shared-directory, copy-item

I have 3 remote servers in my hand. Let us say Server X, Server Y and Server Z. I am running my powershell script from my local machine to login to Remote Server X. This Server X is my base server which has access to other 2 servers. I want to use this Server X as base server and want to copy files from Server Y to Server Z which is impossible through my local machine because of access permissions. So I logged in to Server X using admin credentials which has access to all 3 servers. After logging in, I am just mentioning copy-item command to copy files from shared path of Server Y to Shared Path of Server Z.

This is a similar question to many in this website here goes a twist. When I am debugging, it is showing completed but I am not getting any results. So I tried running this powershell script directly in Server X which contains only copy-item command and source and destination paths of shared folders. When I am debugging I am getting error that, user doesn't have permissions or path is not found. When I am trying to copy and paste files from shared path manually using the same credentials, it is working. But through powershell script, it's now working. I know the reason. It's because of symbol '$' in the shared paths. So I need the solution for this. It is not allowing '$' symbol in my source and destination paths. Is there any alternative for this? If I try to remove that symbol and copy the files, I get the 'Access Denied' Error as it is a shared path, E drive should prefixed with $ symbol.

Here goes my code:

```
 #Calling my Server Name, Credentials from App.Config File 

$currentDirectory = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path)
 $appConfigFile = [IO.Path]::Combine($currentDirectory, 'App.config')
 $appConfig = New-Object XML
 $appConfig.Load($appConfigFile)

 $ServerName = $appConfig.configuration.appSettings.add[0].value
 $Username = $appConfig.configuration.appSettings.add[1].value
 $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $appConfig.configuration.appSettings.add[2].value -AsPlainText -Force 

 $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $Username,$Password
```

## Logging to Server X using credentials and copying files from Server Y to Server Z

```
 Invoke-command -ComputerName $ServerName -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { 

 Copy-Item "\\ServerY\E$\SourceTestFolder\Test.docx" "\\ServerZ\E$\DestTestFolder" }
```

Comment: Do you mean `$E` or `E$` ? The former is a variable, latter is administrative share. Entirely different things.

Comment: I am sorry. My mistake. It's E$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea: Replace the `"` with `'`. So powershell stops to fall over the $-symbols. The way you have written it now says: "Hey powershell, go ahead and look for a variable named $E and put it in there".

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. It was my mistake. It's E$. Not $E. And I tried replacing the quotations. It is working when I am running the command directly in Server X. But when I am running the script from my local machine. It is throwing me Access Denied error as below

Comment: Access is denied
    + CategoryInfo     : PermissionDenied: (\\ServerX...TestFile.txt:String) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName  : ServerX
 
Cannot find path '\\ServerX\SourceTestFolder\TestFile.txt' because it does not exist.
    + CategoryInfo       : ObjectNotFound: (\\ServerX...TestFile.txt:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
    + PSComputerName   : ServerX

Comment: How do you call the script from the local machine?

Answer (score 0):

Like previously metioned you can change the double qoutes to single qoutes. By doing this you say to powershell that everything between is a string without variables.

You can also work with a replace and a special symbol like this example.

But what if you have a string with a $ sign in the path and a varriable. something like this `$cmd = "sc config something$$variable depend= something/something.`

I need the first dollar sign because it is in the name of the service but then it is the variable. What i did was fix it by doing the following.

```
$cmd = "sc config something#$variable depend= something/something"
$cmd = $cmd -replace "#", '$'
```

By doing this powershell fills in the variable so i have `$cmd = "sc config something#value depend= something/something"`

Then I replace the # by the DollarSign and we are set.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply. It's my mistake. It's not $E. It's E$. That indicates admin share. So is it still required to replace $ symbol with #

Comment: Well sinds it is only as a path the easiest thing would be to replace the double qoutes to single qoutes. Then you indicate that everything between should be handled as a string. so Copy-Item "\\ServerY\E$\SourceTestFolder\Test.docx" "\\ServerZ\E$\DestTestFolder" } becomes Copy-Item '\\ServerY\E$\SourceTestFolder\Test.docx' '\\ServerZ\E$\DestTestFolder' }